# Dependency Injection in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8

Does anyone know of decent Dependency Injection framework for windows phone 8? I'm creating a project following mvvm which shares code with a windows store project. I was using Unity for the windows store app, but I can't get it to work with windows phone. Has anyone had similar problems?

Comment: It would probably help to specify what issues you are seeing with Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to download the source from unity and I got it to compile with minimal problems.

http://unity.codeplex.com/releases

Answer (score 2):

"MVVM Light" also comes with "Simple IoC". It works nicely.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [MEF](http://nuget.org/packages/microsoft.composition). Just reference the assemblies in `portable-net45+win8` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried funq from codeplex?

http://funq.codeplex.com/